# Cannot instal MP495 Canon on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

there!

I'm trying to install MP495 on my computer and I've tried 2 approaches:

1. I've added the Device Uri (found on my modem) however when I try to print a page, the printer is not responding
2. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2216359
   I've followed **pdc** instructions, however when I click on the localhost link it still says that with MP495 the computer is Unable to get the printer status.

I've installed both the scanner and printer driver. Still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I installed MP495 in Ubuntu 14.04:

1. Download Canon driver [from their site](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0100301501.html). I downloaded `cnijfilter-mp495series-3.40-1-deb.tar.gz`.
2. Canon driver needs `libtiff4`. Download libtiff4 from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/. I downloaded `libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb`.
3. Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Navigate to where the downloaded files are:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   ```
4. Install `libtiff4`:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
   ```
5. Extract the tar archive:

   ```
   tar zxvf mp495series-3.40-1-deb.tar.gz
   cd cnijfilter-mp495series-3.40-1-deb/packages
   ```
6. Install Canon common package and MP495 package:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i cnijfilter-common_3.40-1_amd64.deb cnijfilter-mp495series_3.40-1_amd64.deb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

libtiff4 requires multiarch-support, which is not installed.
Before Install libtiff4 go to [How do I add multiarch support to install Packet Tracer 7.2.2 on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247658/how-do-i-add-multiarch-support-to-install-packet-tracer-7-2-2-on-ubuntu-20-04) and as it says:

download the file

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```

install with dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
```